# Why does this simple Makefile go into an infinite loop?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

The command "make clean" causes this simple Makefile to go into an infinite loop, spawning process after process, if the directory `m1` does not exist:

```
clean-1:
        cd m1; make clean

clean: clean-1
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with recursive make.  Can anyone explain why this happens, and the best way to prevent it, just in case some user has decided they didn't need directory m1?

Comment: Try `cd m1 && make clean`

Comment: So, I'm guessing "cd m1" fails.  But then the shell forgets all about that and sees "clean", and then tries to do "clean" *in the top level make*, which leads it back to "clean-1" again, etc. etc.  Is that right?

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: More info can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19504-01/802-5880/make-18/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

What you want is basically call `make clean` in the subdirectory `m1`.
But if `m1` is not a directory, you don't want make to do anything at all?

If yes, this is for you:

```
clean-1:
    cd m1 && make clean

clean: clean-1
```

There is one thing to keep in mind with this solution: If there is no directory `m1`, the `make`-command will exit with a non-zero status-code.

```sh
╭─ /tmp
╰─❯ cat Makefile   

clean-1:
    cd m1 && make clean

clean: clean-1

╭─ /tmp
╰─❯ make clean

cd m1 && make clean
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: m1: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:2: clean-1] Error 1
```

Comment: You don't need to use `[ -d m1 ]`.  You can just try the `cd` directly and it will fail if `m1` is not a valid directory.  The nice thing about that is that you'll actually get an error message from `cd` which you can use to understand what happened, rather than simply a message like `exit 1` when the test fails.

Comment: And you're absolutely right. I've updated my answer.